# Regular expression starting with letter only not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4g5ms1xt/) where I am able to restrict the validation to numbers, characters, no spaces and underscores using this : regexp: /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/.

However, I want to start it using letter only and not with number or special character or anything else. I tried this: regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/, but it doesn’t work.

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getConcepts() {

    var bootstrapValidator = $("#validateForm").data('bootstrapValidator');
    bootstrapValidator.validate();
    if (bootstrapValidator.isValid()) {
      $("#validateForm").submit();
      console.log("Submitting form after validation");
    } else {
      console.log("Bootstrap fields are not validated");
      return;
    }
  }

  $("#conceptsButton").click(getConcepts);

  //BEGIN FORM Validations
  $('#validateForm').bootstrapValidator({
    feedbackIcons: {
      valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
      invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
      validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {

      titleOfResearchProject: {
        validators: {
          stringLength: {
            min: 4,
            max: 10,
            message: 'Please Enter the title with minimum 4 & max 10 characters'
          },
          notEmpty: {
            message: 'Please Enter title of your project'
          },
          regexp: {
            //regexp: /^[\w]+$/,
            //regexp: /^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/,   
            regexp: /^[a-zA-Z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/,
            message: 'You can introduce just alphabetical characters, underscore, number but no spaces'
          }
        }
      },



    }
  });

  //END FORM Validations


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- BEGIN Bootstrap form testing-->
<form class="form-horizontal" id="validateForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">

      <div class="form-group">

      </div>



      <div class="form-group">

      </div>


    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Title of your research project:</label>
        <input name="titleOfResearchProject" placeholder="Enter your title here...." class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

      </div>


    </div>
  </div>


  <button class="btn btn-success" id="conceptsButton">Request Data</button>

</form>

<div id="add_dialog" title="Add New Data" style="display:none;">

</div>
```

Comment: Your regexp requires at least two characters. To allow a single character, change the second `+` to `*`.

Comment: PLease you should not use *, this means 0 or n. I have tested your regex and works fine: /^[a-zA-Z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/.test('1abc') evaluates to false, but it will not match if starts with a letter and contains whitespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex: `^[a-zA-Z].*\w+`